# How can I make a Panel change background color while hovering in annotated 7.5 Vaadin?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7, mousehover

I am working on a `Vaadin 7.5.3` project with an annotated servlet configuration.

My main UI class is:

```
@Title("Forms")
@Theme("valo")
public class FormsUI extends UI {

    Panel container = new Panel();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        configureComponents();
        buildLayout();
    }


    private void configureComponents() {

    }

    private void buildLayout() {
        setContent(container);
    }


    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*")
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = FormsUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class FormsServlet extends VaadinServlet {

    }
}
```

My POM (not complete) is:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <vaadin.version>7.5.3</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

That's pretty much it. So the whole CSS (`valo` theme) is defined in the `vaadin-themes` dependency (I believe).

What I want to do is change the background color of a Panel (or, actually ANY component) when my mouse hovers over it.  Super simple in pure CSS.

Every example I find online indicates adding custom CSS classes which I can do.  But where do I define them?  How do I load them?

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I finally solved the issue.  I am not a CSS guy and I know even less about SASS.

Anyway, what I did was extract the `vaadin-themes-7.5.3` folder from my `target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT` (or wherever your exploded war is) and copy it into `src/main/webapp`.

Then, I created a new folder under `../webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme`.

Under `mytheme`, I deleted everything except:

```
favicon.ico
styles.scss
```

I then created:

```
mytheme.scss
```

Inside`styles.scss`, I replaced with:

```
@import "mytheme.scss";

.mytheme {
    @include mytheme;
}
```

Inside `mytheme.scss`, I replaced with:

```
$v-background-color: #777;

@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
    @include valo;
}
```

Works great.

I can now at least start adding custom CSS rules.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

With the annotation `@Theme("valo")`in your UI class, you define which theme (read CSS styles) you will be using.

To be able to have your own CSS styles, you inherit it from the `valo`theme and then there define your own CSS styles in the scss file.

The build process the compiles the scss files into css files.

So you define `@Theme("mytheme")`instead of the valo theme.
In the `VAADIN/themes/mytheme`folder you then put your scss files, which inherit from the valo theme.

The [book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html) has more details on this.

Comment: Right.  And I've done that in the past when I setup Vaadin the "manual" way.  But where exactly is the "valo" theme so I can duplicate it and make changes?  Those two files above are literally all I have in my project.